# Programmatically detect patterns in a set of data?

Tags: java, php

Is there a way to programmatically detect a pattern in a set of data? For example, if I had the following data, how I find that the first column repeats for every 6th row and the second column repeats for every 7th row?

```
2   3
1   1
5   2
4   5
3   7
2   6
1   3
5   1
4   2
3   5
2   7
```

The actual data is far more complex than this. I can use PHP or Java. Is there a library or function for this?

Comment: The short answer is yes you can do this programmatically, but no there is no library or function for arbitrarily detecting random patterns in sets of numbers.

Comment: If you can enumerate all the patterns you want to look for, then yes, you can write some code to detect them.

Comment: Trying to understand compression algorithms like LZW might help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any great references handy, but for these fairly simple patterns, you would want to do [auto correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).  Basically, you see how well the array correlates with itself with various deltas.  It is defined so that +1 means the numbers are perfectly correlated, 0 means they are "perfectly" random with respect to each other, and -1 means that they are perfectly "opposite" of each other.

For a delta = 0, you are comparing the data to itself, to  there is perfect correlation all the time

In your case, the first column will also show a peak (a number nearly 1) with a delta of 6, and the 2nd columns with a delta of 7.

For Java, I'd check the [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the brute force way. The idea is to test all the subsets of the array (first element, then the first two elements, then the first three elements, etc...) and see if any of those appear as patterns in the array.

I wrote this on the spot, so no guarantees :)

```
boolean hasPattern(int[] data) {
    ArrayList<Integer> matchList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        matchList.add(i);

        if (matchPattern(data, matchList))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

boolean matchPattern(int[] data, ArrayList<Integer> pattern) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        if (data[i] != pattern.get(i % pattern.size())
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `matchList.add(i)` with `matchList.add(data[i])` and then it works great:

```
static boolean hasPattern(int[] data) {
    ArrayList<Integer> matchList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        matchList.add(data[i]);

        if (matchPattern(data, matchList))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

static boolean matchPattern(int[] data, ArrayList<Integer> pattern) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        if (data[i] != pattern.get(i % pattern.size())) {
            return false;
        }

    return true;
}
```