# Figuring out the next number(s) in a pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, math

How would I figure out the next number to come in a pattern programatically in C#?
For example, if i had a pattern (3, 6, 9, 12), how would I programatically figure out that the next number is 15, and then 21, and so on?
Thanks.

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Comment: http://oeis.org/  +WebRequest ...........

Comment: The next number might be 4. http://oeis.org/A103695

Comment: this is harder than you would think.. unless you cut down the number of possible patterns

Comment: I would think about this question further.

Comment: Where did you get that assumption from? 3,6,9,12,16,20,24,28,32, 37,42,47,52,57,62,68... Assumption that there is a pattern, that there are enough data points to identify it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: It is not possible to find *the* intended number; but is very possible to produce a pattern, and *an* answer fitting the pattern. It may or may not be the pattern that the asker had in mind, but it would be a valid answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need to know the type of pattern or programatically figure that out. Linear number patterns increase by addition or subtraction. Exponential patterns increase by multiplication or division. With that, you have to start at the first number and determine the difference. Then look at the next number and see if it increases by the same amount. If it does, you have the pattern and just add the difference to the last number. If its not, its an exponential function and then you need to determine how much it increases with each number in the pattern, to project the next one.

Without seeing code, I can only show you the concept. Hope it helps!
You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958573/programmatically-detect-patterns-in-a-set-of-data) useful.

Comment: @KenKin Thanks! Algebra class helps!

Answer (score 2):

Dangit, my response got lost with wireless failure. Lemme try again:

You could do it as a breadth-first search on combinations from a RPN language. Start with your pattern on the stack; ignore stack underflows, as they indicate that you're at the sequence seed. Use basic operators and single digits, for a good balance between expressive power and not exploding the search space too much. For example (and obviously, showing only some interesting points in the search space):

```
for +:
3 +: Stack Underflow - ignore
3 6 +: 9
3 6 9 +: 15 - wrong

for *:
3 *: SU
3 6 *: 18 - wrong

for 1:
3 1: 1 - wrong

for + -:
3 + -: SU
3 6 + -: SU
3 6 9 + -: -12 - wrong

for 3 +:
3 3 +: 6
3 6 3 +: 9
3 6 9 3 +: 12
success
next:
3 6 9 12 3 +: 15
3 6 9 12 15 3 +: 18
```

This will produce the simplest explanation for the sequence. As Samuel Edwin Ward notes, for all we know, there could be a complex algorithm that produces 4 as the next item, or "banana", for that matter. For instance, many people here would instantly "know" the next term in this sequence:

```
1
2
"fizz"
4
?
```

(The answer is, "obviously", `"buzz"`, even though the pattern is not actually demonstrated in the example, only our experience.)

EDIT: Stack Underflow, not Overflow :/

Comment: 1. choose whatever numbers you want

Comment: 2. define the pattern as "numbers produced by my program"